# Delphi FMX dcpcrypt wrong result on macOS 64-bit

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am using Delphi 10.3.2
I am trying to use the DCPCrypt units with the firemonkey framework to encrypt a string.
It works 100% on Win32, Win64 and macOS 32 targets, the result is always the same. But when I compile for macOS 64, the result is different.

This is the code used:

```
function EncodeAES(code:ansistring; key:ansistring):string;
var
    s,u:ansistring;
  enc: TEncoding;
  k,iv, Data, Crypt: TBytes;
  Cipher: TDCP_rijndael;
begin
    u:='';
    enc:=TEncoding.ANSI;
    Data := enc.GetBytes(code); // VMpuXJGbUNOv
    k:=enc.GetBytes(key);   // kj3214ed)k32nre2
    iv:=enc.GetBytes(u);
    Cipher:=TDCP_rijndael.Create(nil);
    Cipher.Init(K[0], 128, @iv[0]);
    Crypt:=Copy(Data, 0, Length(Data));
    BytePadding(Crypt, Cipher.BlockSize, pmPKCS7);
    Cipher.EncryptECB(Crypt[0], Crypt[0]);
    Cipher.Free;
    s:=tencoding.ANSI.GetString(crypt);
    result:=StringToHex(s);
end;
```

and this is the BytePadding function:

```
procedure BytePadding(var Data: TBytes; BlockSize: integer; PaddingMode: TPaddingMode);
var
    I, DataBlocks, DataLength, PaddingStart, PaddingCount: integer;
begin
    BlockSize := BlockSize div 8;
    if PaddingMode in [pmZeroPadding, pmRandomPadding] then
        if Length(Data) mod BlockSize = 0 then Exit;
    DataBlocks := (Length(Data) div BlockSize) + 1;
    DataLength := DataBlocks * BlockSize;
    PaddingCount := DataLength - Length(Data);
    if PaddingMode in [pmANSIX923, pmISO10126, pmPKCS7] then
        if PaddingCount > $FF then Exit;
    PaddingStart := Length(Data);
    SetLength(Data, DataLength);
    case PaddingMode of
        pmZeroPadding, pmANSIX923, pmISO7816: // fill with $00 bytes
            FillChar(Data[PaddingStart], PaddingCount, 0);
        pmPKCS7: // fill with PaddingCount bytes
            FillChar(Data[PaddingStart], PaddingCount, PaddingCount);
        pmRandomPadding, pmISO10126: // fill with random bytes
            for I := PaddingStart to DataLength-1 do Data[I] := Random($FF);
    end;
    case PaddingMode of
        pmANSIX923, pmISO10126:
            Data[DataLength-1] := PaddingCount; // set end-marker with number of bytes added
        pmISO7816:
            Data[PaddingStart] := $80; // set fixed end-markder $80
    end;
end;
```

I call the function like:

```
procedure TForm1.BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    s:string;
begin
    s:=EncodeAES('VMpuXJGbUNOv','kj3214ed)k32nre2');
end;
```

Result with Win32/Win64/macOS 32 (correct):
E32A9DE47CC60BDB70CA27885128D17A

Result with macOS 64 (wrong):
CF622155545E485AC3A083E8A0478493

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Argh!!!! Not again. So many questions which treat binary and text as interchangeable. Please make it stop! Seriously though, encryption algorithms operate on binary. Your encryption functions need to use byte arrays as input and output.

Comment: I assume when the data, crypt, iv and k variables are declared as TBytes, they ARE byte arrays.

Comment: @Softtouch yes they are, but you are responsible for populating them with valid bytes correctly and consistently across machines/platforms, and your `EncodeAES()` code is simply not doing that.

Comment: DCPCrypt2 has an incorrect definition in DCPcrypt2.pas. dword = longword should be: dword = Cardinal. Longword is 8 bytes on 64-bit Posix systems

Comment: @DaveNottage I would opt for `UInt32` instead of `Cardinal`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point; thanks

Comment: @DaveNottage and Remy Lebeau: I changed it from longword to uint32 and now it encrypt just fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encryption operates on binary data, not textual data.  When dealing with text, you have to encode characters to bytes before encryption, and then decode bytes to characters after decryption.  Which means using the same character encoding before encryption and after decryption.  You are attempting to do that encoding, but you are not accounting for the fact that `TEncoding.ANSI` is NOT portable across OS platforms, or even across different machines using the same OS platform.  For better portability, you need to use a consistent encoding, such as `TEncoding.UTF8`.

Also, `TEncoding` operates only with `UnicodeString`, so using `TEncoding.GetBytes()` and `TEncoding.GetString()` with `AnsiString` will perform implicit conversions between ANSI and Unicode using the *RTL's* definition of ANSI, not *yours*, producing bytes you are likely not expecting if your strings contain any non-ASCII characters in them.

Your `EncodeAES()` function is best off using `(Unicode)String` for all of its string handling and forget that `AnsiString` even exists.  Although platforms like Linux are largely UTF-8 systems, Delphi's default `(Unicode)string` uses UTF-16 on all platforms.  If you want to encode ANSI strings, use `RawByteString` to avoid any implicit conversions if calling code wants to use `UTF8String`, `AnsiString(N)`, etc. Encrypt the 8bit characters as-is without using `TEncoding` at all.  Use `TEncoding` only for `UnicodeString` data.

Lastly, your `EncodeAES()` function should not be decoding encrypted bytes to a `UnicodeString` just to convert that to a hex string.  You should be hex-encoding the encrypted bytes as-is.

Try this instead:

```pascal
function EncodeAES(const Data: TBytes; const Key: string): string; overload;
const
  Hex: array[0..15] of Char = ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F');
var
  enc: TEncoding;
  iv, k, Crypt: TBytes;
  Cipher: TDCP_rijndael;
  B: Byte;
  I: Integer;
begin
  enc := TEncoding.UTF8;
  iv := enc.GetBytes('');
  k := enc.GetBytes(Key);

  Cipher := TDCP_rijndael.Create(nil);
  try
    Cipher.Init(k[0], 128, @iv[0]);
    Crypt := Copy(Data, 0, Length(Data));
    BytePadding(Crypt, Cipher.BlockSize, pmPKCS7);
    Cipher.EncryptECB(Crypt[0], Crypt[0]);
  finally
    Cipher.Free;
  end;

  SetLength(Result, Length(Crypt)*2);
  I := Low(Result);
  for B in Crypt do
  begin
    Result[ I ] := Hex[(B shr 4) and $F];
    Result[I+1] := Hex[B and $F];
    Inc(I, 2);
  end;
end;

function EncodeAES(const S, Key: string): string; overload;
begin
  Result := EncodeAES(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(S), Key);
end;

function EncodeAES(const S: RawByteString; const Key: string): string; overload;
begin
  Result := EncodeAES(BytesOf(S), Key);
end;
```

Comment: Fully understood this now. Unfortunately, there must be still something in the dcpcrypt components causing it to fail when the string to encrypt is longer than 15 character. I am using normally TMS Cryptography Pack, which works correct, but they did not update to macOS 64 as of now and my projects cant be compiled, so I was looking for another solution.

Comment: I encrypt 111111111111111 (15x1) with key 1111111111111111 (15x1).

Online tools, my own encryption code and other Win32 components return all the same:
FD97A42377D8235121E41640B935BDDD


Now I add one more 1, so its 16x1.
Online tools, and other Win32 components return all the same:
AD0110483D0559D12E8CB97203E6C908F30C69C4F945E654EBD4B388B1C8F790

But my own code based on DCPCrypt return:
AD0110483D0559D12E8CB97203E6C90810101010101010101010101010101010

I used the example code from Remy above.
What am I doing wrong? I dont get it...